# VB.Net "mask" combo box text as another text

Tags: mysql, vb.net

So I have a combobox which contains table names from a MySql database they are automatically listed using `show tables` query upon form load.

Is there anyway to show something else in the combobox but the text value still being the original table name?

Comment: Yes.  Haven't touched WinForms in quite a while, but I think that the comboboxes have `.Text` and `.Value` properties.  If not, then you would need to use a `Dictionary` or similar data structure and set the table name as the key and something else as the value.

Comment: @DouglasBarbin Perhaps you should do some quick testing before suggesting something with not too much applicability.

Comment: You can store all the information from the DB into a temporary collection which you can edit before setting it as the combobox DataSource; or you might add the combobox items one by one by performing the corresponding editions "on the go". By default, the ComboBox items are just a collection of simple strings.

Comment: @varocarbas I think you missed the point where he wants to preserve the original values from the database.

Comment: @DouglasBarbin I didn't miss anything. I have proposed the conventional solution for what the OP wants. You cannot affect the .Text/.Value properties as you suggest (ComboBox items don't have such properties, as something you can add/remove).

Comment: @varocarbas So how would he know which values in the ComboBox correspond to which values from the database?

Comment: @DouglasBarbin ??!! Let me try it again: you have recommended the OP to do something which IS IMPOSSIBLE (you cannot make a 2-parts storage for each item in the ComboBox). I have suggested what seems the most evident way (= not plugging the DB info directly to the ComboBox; that is: either modifying the DataSource or adding a modified version of the items one by one); didn't say anything else. Logically, if you have a listA of items from the DB and a listB (modified version of listA) in the Combobox, you would have to set a relationship between both sources, but not via .Text/.Value.

Comment: @DouglasBarbin PS: it should have been clear (at least, from my second comment), that I referred to the .Text/.Value alternative. The Dictionary suggestion is one of the possible options but this is secondary as far as the main concern here is knowing how to populate the combobox (the Dictionary is just for relational purposes between both versions).

Answer (score 1):

It isn't impossible.  Here is a trivial example:

```
Public Class Form1

  Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    ' This would be whatever you are pulling from the database.  For the purpose of this example, it is just mock data.
    Dim dataFromDatabase As IEnumerable(Of String) = {"1st table from db", "2nd table from db", "etc."}

    ' What you actually want to display in the combobox.  It should be in the same order as above and have the same number of items.  Items must be unique.
    Dim valuesToDisplayInComboBox As IEnumerable(Of String) = {"1st item", "2nd item", "3rd item"}


    ' This is what ties the two together.  You would probably want this to be larger in scope than this example.
    Dim dataCollection As New Dictionary(Of String, String)   
    For i As Integer = 0 To dataFromDatabase.Count - 1 Step 1
      dataCollection.Add(valuesToDisplayInComboBox(i), dataFromDatabase(i))
    Next

    ComboBox1.DataSource = valuesToDisplayInComboBox

  End Sub
End Class
```

Now you have a `Dictionary` that links the 2 together, so whenever the user selects something in the combobox, you would go to the `Dictionary` and look up the corresponding table name.

Comment: If the "it isn't impossible" intends to be an answer to my comment, I am afraid that this code does not reflect what I was saying that was impossible. Can your please indicate me where the .Text/.Value parts come into picture? The only thing I see in your code is "over-DataSourcing", that is, providing more data than what the given control can deal with. Result: the control ignores half of the information you are feeding to it. If your intention was proving this point ("when you provide 2 times more than what is required, the control ignores half of it"), then you are right.

Comment: I said that I thought that comboboxes in WinForms might have `.Text`/`.Value`.  I also said "If not, then another solution is...".  Since the Windows Forms ComboBox can only bind to a 1D datasource, there are various workarounds to achieve what the OP is trying to achieve.  To simply say that it can't be done is a little bit misleading.  It can't be done using a ComboBox alone, but he never said that he could only use a ComboBox.

Comment: I proposed this alternative since the first comment (= create a temporary DataSource from the DB, etc.). The only think which I said that was impossible is the .Text/.Value part. You effectively said that you were not sure about this part, but then what was the point of continue our discussion? I said very clearly than the only impossible bit was relying on .Text/.Value. Why I will say that it is impossible to create a 2D collection??!! But well... after I saw/read yesterday from various persons I am starting to doubt on the good faith/understanding here....

Comment: @varocarbas It was just a simple misunderstanding between us.  No worries.  Enjoy the rest of your day.

Comment: (I always enjoy every second :)) but let me clarify what you mean with "misunderstanding": You saying something completely wrong + the statement "Haven't touched WinForms in quite a while" (despite being advising in winforms) + I correcting your error = long discussion to nowhere. Usually I let these things like this but yesterday I met quite a few peculiar people and promised myself to clarify everything, just in case that I and the other person are talking completely different languages (what might be the case here).

Comment: Also and, please, don't take it personally, I am not too much into misunderstandings and long discussions/explanations (if are required/helpful, I don't have any problem; but when there seems to not be any way through, I am a pretty practical guy) and so, in order to avoid problems, and by being completely sure that you are a really nice guy (although not quite thinking like I do), I hope that you will not mind if I reduce our communication to its minimal expression (you know? To avoid misunderstandings).

Answer (score 1):

```
Class Element
    Public ItemName as String = ""
    Public ItemData As Object = Nothing     
    ' Object allows it to be reusable beyond this use

    Public Sub New(iName as String, iData As Object)
         ItemName = iName
         ItemData = iData
    End Sub

    Public overrides Function ToString As String
       Return ItemName
    End sub
End Class

....

For each s as string in listoftablesfromdatabase
  ' dont know how you are getting your list, 
  ' but here is one way to alias them
  Dim El as Element

  Select Case s
       Case "tbl_event_birthdays_september"
           El = New Element("September Birthdays", s)
       case ...
       case ...
   End Select
   ComboBox1.Items.Add(el)
 Next s
```

The class will automatically use the friendly name you gave it.  To get the real selected item name:

```
  realName = ComboBox1.SelectedItem.ItemData.Tostring
```

might not need the .ToString   This is not a lot different than Douglas Barbin's idea, it still associates 2 strings, it just doesnt use a dictionary.  Alternatively, you could store the Elements in a List(of Element) or Dictionary and bind it to the datasource as Douglas showed.

If the user comes back to the Combo over and over, then do use a List or Dictionary, but not temporary - build it once and use it over and over.

Comment: Please, be clear on what Douglas's idea is doing (because there were some comments above which perhaps might be misunderstood): you can feed to the Combobox just a 1D datasource (a list of strings, an array of strings, etc.). If you want to create a 2D element and use one of its dimensions to feed the combobox, is fine. But what you cannot do is populating two different combobox dimensions as Douglas suggested (which I said that is impossible but which he does not seem to want to recognise): you cannot feed two different properties (.Text/.Value) for each item in the Combobox.

Comment: So... proper answer to the OP: is there any way to "mask" what the combobox shows? NO (by relying only on the combobox). But you can set up a 2D dataset relating what the combobox shows (its datasource) with another list of values (which the combobox is not even aware of) -> this is what both your answers are about.

Comment: @varocarbas You are really arguing semantics at this point in an attempt to prove me incorrect.  None of your responses have been even remotely helpful to the OP.  If you have a better solution than the two that have been posted, then, by all means, post your solution.

Comment: my only reference to Douglas' solution regards binding a List or Dictionary to a cbo. The OP did **not** ask how to mask (or alias) something using *"ONLY a cbo"* - he wants to hide some poorly named tables(e.g. 'tbl_event_birthdays_september').

Comment: @DouglasBarbin my whole discussion with you started because you suggested something impossible: .Text/.Value. Why a simple correction (ey! Don't say that) has driven to a so long discussion is something which still I don't know.

Comment: I was just intending to make the point clear (Douglas' answer starts with "It isn't impossible. Here is a trivial example:", apparently referring to our conversion above). In any case, the OP seems to be looking for a way to mask the values directly from the combobox; although I guess that this is point is clear already.

Comment: @DouglasBarbin PS: I don't discuss about semantics never (actually, don't like too much people doing it; I prefer to understand the real intention); regarding my answer, I wrote it in my second comment: "You can store all the information from the DB into a temporary collection which you can edit before setting it as the combobox DataSource; or you might add the combobox items one by one by performing the corresponding editions "on the go". By default, the ComboBox items are just a collection of simple strings." PPS "prove me incorrect" whaaaattt?! I guess that better stop this conversation.